# Input field not appending to td

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create a table with an input field dynamically but my code ends up creating an empty table.

```
  var calcDiv = document.getElementById("calc_div");
  var calcTab = document.createElement('TABLE');
  var tbody = document.createElement('TBODY');

  var calcForm = document.createElement('FORM');
  calcForm.id = "calculator_form";

  //calc display
  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
  var td = document.createElement('TD');
  td.colspan = "4";
  var comp = document.createElement('INPUT');
  comp.type = "text";
  comp.value = 0;
  comp.disabled = true;
  comp.id = "compDisplay";
  td.appendChild(comp); //THIS DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK
  tr.appendChild(td);
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
  calcForm.appendChild(comp);

  calcTab.appendChild(tbody);
  calcTab.style.width = "500px";
  calcTab.style.height = "500px";
  calcDiv.appendChild(calcTab);
```

Comment: I created a JSFiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/j42L9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing a line and were incorrectly appending another. In:

```
tr.appendChild(td);
tbody.appendChild(tr);
calcForm.appendChild(comp);
```

You needed to:

```
tr.appendChild(td);
tbody.appendChild(tr); 
calcTab.appendChild(tbody); <-- append the tbody to the table
calcForm.appendChild(calcTab); <-- append the table to the form
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PF3z2/1)**

This produces the HTML:

```
<div id="calc_div">
    <table style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" disabled="" id="compDisplay">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Note that you may also want to use `td.setAttribute('colspan','4');` instead of `td.colspan = "4";`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you are adding the input named "comp" again in the form  after two rows? "calcField.addChild(comp)"

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is you're appending `comp` to the `td`, then appending it to the `form` after that. This removes it from the table it was in and puts it in the form, which isn't attached anywhere in your document.

[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/37sS7/1/) with the appending to the form commented out. Or perhaps you'd prefer to append the form to the `td` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think this method will help you out. I've coded it so that the appendChild follows the DOM tree. Take a look. *Note: I created a variable to append the target "calc_div" to the document body. Feel free to take that out*.

```
var div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
div.id = "calc_div";

var table = div.appendChild(document.createElement('table'));
table.style.width = "500px";
table.style.height = "500px";

var tbody = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));
var trow = tbody.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));

var tcell = trow.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
tcell.colSpan = "4";

var input = tcell.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
input.id = "compDisplay";
input.type = "text";
input.value = 0;
input.disabled = true;
```